# Let $X'_n(x) = nX_{n-1}(x)$ and $X_1(x) = \frac{-4 \cdot 1!}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{cos(\pi x (2n+1))}{(2n+1)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $X'_n(x) = nX_{n-1}(x)$ and $X_1(x) = \frac{-4 \cdot 1!}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{cos(\pi x (2n+1))}{(2n+1)^2}$
Use integration on (0,1) to show that $X_2(x) = \frac{-4 \cdot 2!}{\pi^3}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{sin(\pi x (2n+1))}{(2n+1)^3}$.

Attempt.

$$X'_2(x) = 2X_1(x)$$
$$X_2(x) = 2\int_{0}^{1}X_1(x)dx$$
$$= 2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{-4 \cdot 1!}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{cos(\pi x (2n+1))}{(2n+1)^2}dx$$
$$= \frac{-4 \cdot 2 \cdot1!}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{cos(\pi x (2n+1))}{(2n+1)^2}dx$$
$$=\frac{-4 \cdot 2!}{\pi^3}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{sin(\pi x (2n+1))}{(2n+1)^3}dx + c$$

how do you find c here?

Answer (score 0):

There ia no constant, this is a definite integral
$F(a)+c-F(b)-c$ where the $F(x)$ is the primitive integral of the $f(x)$ function, in the Newton-Leibnitz integral the constant cancels out.